# Return View("NameOfTheView") does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This is the code where i am trying to return a specific view :

EDIT : I call this method using AJAX

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostData(SurveyData surveyData)
    {
        if (SaveRecords(surveyData))
        {
            logger.Write($"Data added to the database successfully!", LogEventLevel.Information);
            return View("ThankYouPage"); //separate view, same layout
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Write($"Failed adding data to the database!!", LogEventLevel.Error);
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

After clicking the "Submit" button, i wait for the data to be written in the database and then show the Thank You Page, which is a static cshtml page, without a model.

While on this method, if "data" is found, i do get the Thank You Page :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string data)
    {
        //check if data exists, return the thank you page
        var found = await _dbContext.SurveyData.AnyAsync(e => e.Data == data);
        if(found)
        {
            return View("ThankYouPage");
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
            return View();
        }
    }
```

From Console :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: 
Executed action method pmi.Controllers.HomeController.PostData (pmi), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 252.3692ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: 
Executing ViewResult, running view ThankYouPage.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: 
Executed ViewResult - view ThankYouPage executed in 6.2028ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: 
Executed action pmi.Controllers.HomeController.PostData (pmi) in 284.9033ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 294.3209ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I get no exception, so what could be going wrong? 
The difference is that one method is async and one not, so could this be the reason?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :

Client side code:

```
$(function () {
$('#Button1').click(function () {
    var radiobutton1 = $('input[name="rb_answer1"]:checked').val();
    var answer1 = $('#answer1').val();
    var radiobutton2 = $('input[name="rb_answer2"]:checked').val();
    var answer2 = $("#answer2").val();
    var Abcde = $("#abcde").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
            url: '/home/postdata/',
        data: {
            ONMBR: Abcde,
            Answer1: radiobutton1,
            Answer11: answer1,
            Answer2: radiobutton2,
            Answer21: answer2 
        },

    });
});
```

})

Comment: Saying it *does not work* isn't really too helpful. What exactly is happening?

Comment: No changes at all, the data is saved in the database but it's still the same view.

Comment: `still the same view` which view? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have view files inside the controller name folder inside Views Folder in solution?

Comment: Is view exists in same folder?

Comment: it's not 100% clear. You're saying that, in the PostData method, it never returns the "Thankyou" view? Do you get the Error view instead, or not? If not, what _does_ happen? How are you calling this method - normal postback, or AJAX? Are there any exceptions logged? Lots of info missing from this question.

Comment: Yes @Md.AbdulAlim

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim Yes it exists.

Comment: @ADyson No, if you see from Console, it calls the ThankYouPage but i don't get to see it in browser. I already said that there are no exeptions. And i am calling it using AJAX

Comment: well you can't really return a full view using AJAX. If you tried to insert that HTML from the AJAX response into your page, it would insert a page within a page (since view returns everything including the layout, i.e. html, head, body tags etc) which would make no sense and probably invalidate your main HTML. So you either return a Partial View, so you can then use JavaScript to insert that HTML snippet generated by the partial view into your current page, or you ditch the AJAX and just use a normal postback, then it will work as expected.

Comment: It looks like the first parameter that the `View` method expects is the model instead of the view name.  Have you tried something like `return View(null, "ThankYouPage")` ?

Comment: @Mun OP is calling the method using AJAX, that's the real issue. We can't see the JS code but I assume they aren't using the response to update the current page. Even if they are, as I explain above, it wouldn't make sense to do so with a full view.

Comment: Are you binding any model which view you want to return?

Comment: @ADyson Yep, you're right.  It looks like the correct view is being returned and the issue is with the ajax call. OP probably needs to provide the client-side code being used to call this to better debug the issue.

Comment: If the other method i have specified above, which is not called by ajax, can return the full view correctly, then this must be reason. I am updating the question with the client side code. @ADyson

Comment: It's not the code which is the issue really, it's the method of calling the code. Just don't use AJAX for this type of thing and you won't have a problem. If you want to redirect to another page / return a whole different view, then using AJAX makes no sense anyway - the whole purpose of AJAX is to allow the browser to send data to the server while remaining on the same page. By all means return some HTML via AJAX by which you can update the current page, but do it by means of a Partial View, not a full view.

Comment: I have to use ajax because i have to post data that i take from users... @ADyson

Comment: "I have to use ajax because i have to post data that i take from user"....er, what? Where did you get that notion? Since when was AJAX required to do that? A normal form postback has been doing that practically since the web was invented, long before anyone thought of AJAX. The only reason to use AJAX instead of a normal postback is if you want to stay on the same page afterwards. You don't want to, so don't use AJAX - just allow your form to be submitted normally.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, never heard of postback... first time working with mvc. Thank you very much @ADyson

Comment: I think you should maybe take the MVC introductory tutorial provided by Microsoft, it shows everything working with normal forms and postback, without any AJAX. Or even any tutorial regarding HTML forms and the architecture of the web in general sounds like it might be helpful. Get the basic concepts about how HTTP and the web works straight in your head before you carry on, or you'll keep tying yourself in knots :-). If you're only just starting in programming in general, write some simple console programs before you try the more complex scenario of client-server programming.

Answer (score 4):

You have no callback to your AJAX, which then of course means you're not actually doing anything with the response. Nothing happens automatically with AJAX. It's on you to take the response (provided to the callback) and do something with it, such as select something in the DOM to insert the returned HTML into. However, that only makes sense if you're returning a partial, i.e. `PartialView`. Returning `View` means you're going to get the full HTML document, complete with all your layout, head, etc.